# Undefined Symbol at Runtime

Tags: c++11, cmake, runtime, ld, abi

We compile and link our code using CMake 3.18 on Ubuntu 18.04. The structure of the program is this:

There's an application with a main function, which loads a shared library at runtime, say lib_a.so. At runtime, this library loads two other libraries, lib_b.so and lib_c.so and uses symbols from them. lib_b.so uses symbols from lib_c.so as well.

lib_b.so and lib_c.so are compiled from submodules B and C of A.

On some systems the code runs fine. On some systems, however, we get undefined symbol error, which looks like this when the symbol that can't be found is demangled using c++filt:

```
Unable to load lib_a.so : lib_b.so: undefined symbol: D::E::Get(std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)
```

Namespace D and class D::E are under a submodule of C. This submodule doesn't contain a CMakeLists.txt, and no shared or static library is produced from it. Its a directory, which contains source and header files only.

When we look at the defined symbols of lib_c.so using nm --defined-only lib_c.so, we see that there's this symbol:

```
D::E::Get(std::initializer_list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)
```

Our G++ version is 7.5.0, and CMake version is 3.18.0.

From this, we gather this is a CXX11 ABI issue. So, these are the things that we tried, separately:

- Adding add_compile_definitions(_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1), before defining the target, to the CMakeLists.txt that compiles and links lib_b.so.
- Adding set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11), before defining the target, to the CMakeLists.txt that compiles and links lib_a.so. As this is the top module, we thought this would set c++ standard to 11 for all of its submodules.
- Adding target_compile_features(target PUBLIC cxx_std_11), before defining the target, to the CMakeLists.txt that compiles and links lib_b.so.

None of solved the problem. Also, there's no change. lib_b.so looks for the same symbol, again.

However, when we write a Makefile that compiles the sources and links the shared libraries as told, the problem disappears.

Comment: You say that "[o]n some systems the code runs fine. On some systems, however, we get undefined symbol error"... Is it always the same systems, can the behavior be replicated reliably? What is the difference between these "systems" where it can run and where it can't?

Comment: So the question is technically "How to build `lib_b.so` library so it will use things from `__cxx11` namespace?", am I correctly understand your problem?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We tried on 4 systems. They mostly have the same hardware. They don't have the same system image, however. All are Ubuntu 18.04. All have CMake 3.18.0. All have GCC 7.5.0. There are third party libraries the the program depends on, and these are the same versions of the same libraries. We don't see a difference that would cause such an issue. I can give more detail if you can say what you want to know.

Comment: @Tsyvarev More or less yes. Except that we add expressions to its CMake file telling to use c++11, and cxx11 abi, without success, and that using Makefile solves the issue, which we can't because of the requirements.

Comment: So your `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't give the desired result, but using a plain `Makefile` do? If you use `CMake` and run a verbose build (to see all the commands and their options), how does that compare to `make` and the commands and options there? All all the command and their options exactly the same? In the same order (order matters)? Is the exact same compiler used? The exact same standard library? The exact same libraries elsewhere (including yours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a third-party library issue.

As @Someprogrammerdude suggested, running CMake with VERBOSE=1 revealed that lib_b.so is linked with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0.

I changed it manually in B/CMakeFiles/B.dir/flags.cmake to -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1. This time the previous error is gone.

This, however, gave another undefined symbol error with cxx11_abi regarding one of the third-party libraries that we use.

Updating the library to a version that's compiled with CXX11 ABI resolved the issue.